# Silverlight alternative to AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I am trying to set the cell templates of the alternate rows of a DataGrid, similar to the "AlternatingRowBackground", but not just for background colour.

Is there an alternative to the "AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle" of the DataGridView?

I can do this programmatically in my own class inheriting of of the DataGrid (using the LoadingRow event). The problem with this is I need to know the index of the row to determine what style to use. I can't seem to find a way of getting the index of a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out there is a GetIndex method on the LoadingRow event, so I can use that to determine which style to assign the row.

```
this.LoadingRow += (s,e) =>
{
    if(e.Row.GetIndex() % 2 == 1)
        e.Row.Style = //alternate Style
};
```